# Auth0 and Socket.IO - correct implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, auth0, feathersjs

I am working on securing socket.io services with Auth0 authentication. On the server, I did the below:

```
app.configure(feathers.socketio(function(io) {
  if(process.env.JWT_AUTH == 'disable' && app.get('env') !== 'production') {
    console.log('*** JWT_AUTH disabled: Free passes today ***');
  } else {
    io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
      secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
      audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      handshake: true
    }));
  }
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}));
```

In order to pass a token with socket.io from the client, I do:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS = 3600;

var createToken = require('auth0-api-tokens')({
  clientId: 'process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID',
  clientSecret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
})

// each key is an entity, each array element is an action
var token = createToken({
  scopes: {
    users: ['read', 'update'],
    clients: ['delete']
  },
  lifetimeInSeconds: TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS
});

console.log("Auth0 token: ", token);

var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000', {
  'query': 'token=' + token});
var app = feathers().configure(feathers.socketio(socket));
```

I am not utilizing token scopes, but I copied them from an example. Should probably not be the problem.

When I turn-on JWT_AUTH, server stops servicing unauthorized [as well as authorized] socket.io requests. Without it, my REST API are protected, but socket.io is not. I need socket.io protected with Auth0. What can I check?

Thank you

Comment: It appears the client is able to generate a valid token. The server just does not process socket.io requests. Have to figure out how to debug that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the below worked:

```
io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  handshake: true
}));
```

secret and handshake without audience.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var createToken = require('auth0-api-tokens')({
>     clientId: 'process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID',
>     clientSecret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
> })
> ```

Since this is running on the client (as your question suggests), make sure you have re-created the `process.env` object on the client so it can access it, and find your environmental variables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
You basically do the same thing as I did, except there is no expiration. I don't think that there was/is a problem with my token, just because it had a timeout. In fact, the token looks good. Something is probably wrong with the server end. I just have not figured out how to debug it.